# Firestore | get DocumentReference's data inside a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection named `users` and another one named `posts` and inside of it a field called `userReference` which contains a reference to a `user/{userId}`
I am trying to get the data in the `DocumentReference` but i can't find a way to do it

```
import {COLLECTIONS, db} from '@/firebase'
import {
  collection,
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
  DocumentReference
} from 'firebase/firestore'
export default function timeline() {
  const colRef = query(collection(db, COLLECTIONS.posts), orderBy('created', 'desc'))
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    onSnapshot(colRef, (querySnapshot) => {
      let posts = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (snapDoc) => {
        const post = snapDoc.data()
        const {created} = post
        let userReference = new DocumentReference(post.userReference)
        posts.push({...post, id: snapDoc.id, created: +created.toDate()})
      })
      resolve(posts)
    }, reject)
  })
}
```

Comment: If the `userReference` field is a document reference field type, then `post.userReference` will already be a `DocumentReference` object. To read that object, you'd `getDocument(post.userReference)`.

Comment: Did you mean `getDoc`? because there's no a function called like that
Anyway i tried with `getDoc(post.userReference)` but it returns an empty object `{}`

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried. Without `getDoc()` it definitely won't work, with it there may be something else that someone spots.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore database with the document corresponding to `snapDoc` open. Also, what do you do with `userReference`? It is not use after the line which declares it.

Comment: [This is how my posts collection looks like](https://imgur.com/XJe1drD)

Comment: userReference meant to be a way to avoid extra queries to db. I mean, i got two collections: `users` and `posts`.
Each `post` owns to an `user` and i were storing `userId` in plain text and then doing the extra request on any post item but it seems to be pretty tricky.

Comment: [and this is what it returns](https://imgur.com/a/FK3Q6hP)
I don't know if the fact that it's inside an `onSnapshot` callback function affects the query.